# Find the shortest path from source to target in a weighted-undirected graph in O(V + E) time

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, complexity-theory, graph-theory

I've been tasked with designing an algorithm that finds the shortest path in an weighted-undirected graph with V nodes and E edges in O(V + E) time. The graph weights are all positive integers and no weight is greater than 15.

I believe I can use Dijkstra's algorithm to find the shortest path from a source node to a target node, but I don't think it satisfies the runtime  constraints.

Knowing at the runtimes of BFS and DFS, I'm thinking that some sort of modification with those algorithms will get me to O(V + E), but I'm not sure what direction to head in or how I can leverage the <= 15 weight constraint on the edges.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Well, if all the node weights were 1, then you ought to pretty easily see how to use bfs from the source. Label each unlabeled node with the distance of its search predecessor back to the source plus one (the first time the search discovers it). When you label the target, that's the answer. But now you've solved the whole problem because you can replace each edge with weight w in the weighted graph with a chain of w edges of unit weight. If you're implementing this, you can avoid actually constructing the new graph. "Simulate" the extra edges during the search with a counter in each node.

Comment: @Gene I think this should be an answer, rather than a comment

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use Dijkstra's algorithm, but you have to be a little careful with the priority queue.

Since all the weights are integers from 1 to 15, there can only be 16 different priorities in the queue at any one time.  You can use this fact to implement all your priority queue operations in constant time.  That will change the complexity of the algorithm from O(|V| + |E| log |V|) to O(|V| + |E|)

There are lots of ways to make that priority queue.  Basically you partition the entries into lists of entries with the same priority, and then you only have to prioritize the 16 lists.  It's reasonable to keep those 16 lists in a circular array.

Answer (score 2):

The algorithm that You're looking for is called Dial's Algorithm as it works also in graphs that contain cycles. It's complexity is `O(E + WV)`. In case, `W>>V` you can replace one bucket per `W` with buckets for weights `1, 2-3, 4-7, 8-15 etc`.

It's an optimization on Dijkstra, which uses the fact, that given the range of weights, You're able to replace the Fibonacci Heap with buckets which will decrease the find_node operation from `O(logn)` to `O(1)`.

The algorithm in detail is well described on [GeeksForGeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/dials-algorithm-optimized-dijkstra-for-small-range-weights/) and [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm#Specialized_variants) among others.

You should also be interested in Directed Acyclic Graph Shortest Path in Cormen's Introduction to Algorithms on p. 655 or on [GeeksForGeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/shortest-path-for-directed-acyclic-graphs/)